# What are these symbols in Garmin Pilot?

Tags: flight-planning, software, aeronautical-charts

When I start editing a flight plan in Garmin Pilot, if I have a distance that is farther (like 1,000 nm or farther) I get these two symbols in the map on the Flight Plan pane:

[image: Symbol that pops up with longer flight plans]

One is a tower and the other is an oval.

Here is the entire pane view:

[image]

Any idea what these two symbols are?

The tower looks like the same symbols as 'obstruction' from the Garmin Pilot manual, but note that the filed altitude is 39,000 feet (ie, no obstacles that high around here.)

What about the little oval?

Comment: I initially thought is was an indicator for 'midway fuel' but changing the initial fuel amount does not move the two symbols...

Comment: The first one is a lighted obstacle that is not a factor due to altitude, I think the second one is sky conditions but still trying to verify.

Comment: *The first one is a lighted obstacle* -- I don't think so. 1) It moves as the flight direction changes; 2) The flight plan is 39,000 feet so every lighted tower is irrelevant. *I think the second one is sky conditions* - Again, I don't think so. The tower and the oval, if present, are always the same distance apart and always right on the rhumb line

Comment: Is this Garmin Pilot for Android or iOS?

Comment: It is iOS. On the new iPad Pro

Comment: If you lower the altitude to something where you would have obstacles, does that change to some number?

Comment: It appears regardless of altitude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are the highest obstacle and highest terrain point along the route, respectively. They're both grey because they're well below your planned altitude, so they're no factor.

You can see them by going to "Flight Plan", "Details", "Highest Point".

Comment: Great! It took me a while to find `Highest Point`. On my version, Press `Flight Plan`; Then press the blue `ⓘ`; The `Highest Point` for the details and Lat / Lon. Makes sense (obviously) that it is always on the rhumb line.

Comment: @dawg I'm on Android, so I'm not surprised it's a bit different!